# R - Conditional replacement of column values in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame which has 2 columns - A & B. I want to replace the values of column B in such a way that, when the `VALUE>=5` replace with `1`, else replace with `0`.
**Note -** There are 2 conditions to be checked.

```
X=read.csv("Y:/impdat.csv")

A   B  
3   16  
12  3  
1   2  
12  9  
4   4  
5   6  
21  1  
4   14  
3   10  
12  1
```

So after replacing, the data should be

```
A   B  
3   1  
12  0  
1   0  
12  1  
4   0  
5   1  
21  0  
4   1  
3   1  
12  0
```

Sounds simple. But I am unable to implement it.
I tried

```
ifelse(X$B>=5,1,0)
```

This only prints the new values, but the original data remains the same.

Comment: Yes it is simple. hint: `ifelse`.

Comment: @agstudy I tried that, but that only prints the values and does not change dataframe X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
X$B <- as.integer(X$B >= 5)
```

will do the trick.

Comment: this will satisfy only 1 of the conditions

Comment: @BalajiSuresh What is the second condition? Please specify the expected outcome.

Comment: Should replace the other values by 0

Comment: Nice it worked! Didn;t know 'as.integer' could be used that way

Answer (score 1):

```
transform(X, B=ifelse(B>=5,1,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it.
Just had to assign the object.

```
    X$B=ifelse(X$B>=5,1,0)
```